# Why if you search for a or A in this very page, you'll not find а nor А?

Tags: unicode, internationalization, language-lawyer, software-design

And even if you search for *p* or *P*, you'll not find *р* nor *Р*.

Why does Unicode use different codepoints for, say, a/A (latin) а/А (cyrillic)? What is the relevance of this from the [software-design](/questions/tagged/software-design) and [i18n](/questions/tagged/i18n) standpoint?

Let me explain where my curiosity lies:

- *a*/*A* are lower/upper case version of the same letter, which is used in

  - italian, where it is pronounced /a/,
  - english, where it is pronounced /a/, /æ/, or /e/ (and probably other shades) depending on the word it appears in,
  - in french, where ...;
- a graphically identical letter *а*/*А* is used in cyrillic, but it is assigned to different code points.

*a*/*A* and *а*/*А* have the same identical shape, and not an entirely different pronounciation, so why are they not the *same* code point (well, the same two for upper case and lower case)?

The only reason I can think of, and which occurred to me only now that I ask the question, is that they belong to different alphabets, and the characters of a given alphabet are better if laid out sequentially, e.g. (in C++) `assert(u'a' + 1 == u'b')` but `assert(u'а' + 1 == u'б')`.

Is that the only true reason? Having alphabets occupy sequential codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all explained in [Unicode Technical Note #26](https://www.unicode.org/notes/tn26/). In short:

Latin and Cyrillic are different scripts, even if some of their letters look very similar to one another. Visual appearance is not the only factor that defines a character’s identity, and letters are generally never unified across scripts. It would just make the Unicode Standard harder to use for everybody.